# Talk via JavaScript to the UART

Tags: javascript

I want to send Data to the UART from JavaScript.
No question (yet) about initialising the UART, but how to send data from JavaScript?

Comment: Did you do some research, such as googling for 'raspberry pi javascript uart' (or 'serial' instead of 'uart')?

Comment: Javascript is sandboxed on the browser in the client.(not on the Pi)  You need a back end service like Node, Python, AspNetCore which can talk to the hardware. You client then sends requests to the server, which then does UART stuff

Comment: No a question about initialising the UART? Then it is a pure JavaScript question and does not belong to Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

I do just that using Node-RED on my Pi, it has serial nodes as part of the basic install. See [Node-RED website](https://nodered.org/docs/)